# Oracle Apex free workspace

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, workspace

Hello I have been waiting since Sunday for a free workspace for Oracle Apex. Does it take this long to get a free workspace, or how can I tell if I was denied a free workspace?... I am taking an online class and wanted to use it for training, per the class recommendation, but haven't heard back from them. Your response is appreciated.. thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing Littlefoot is right and the email went to your junk mail. But here's another suggestion: try the free tier in Oracle Cloud! You get two free databases that can be used for production (unlike apex.oracle.com). https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/ Here's a video that will help get you started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOn3HdoSs6s After the database is up, follow Part 3 in the lab to create your APEX workspace: https://oracle.github.io/learning-library/workshops/apex-atp/?page=1-create-an-apex-workspace.md

Comment: much appreciated, I will try, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, it takes no time at all.

To prove it, I've just requested a workspace on apex.oracle.com and got the "Action required: account request for *me*" e-mail within seconds.

So ... either you did something wrong (such as provided an invalid e-mail address), or perhaps that mail ended up in your Junk mailbox.

Comment: You're welcome; I hope you'll finally get the access.

Answer (score 0):

I used this one and install locally:

https://www.oracle.com/tools/technologies/handsonlab-apex.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give it a try.